# Text jumps on hover scroll bar

Tags: css, hover, scrollbar

I was trying out the on hover scroll bar style that is used in many places but ran into a problem. The appearance of the scroll bar on hovering causes text to jump which looks jarring.

```
#scroll {
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   overflow: hidden;
}


#scroll:hover {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

This [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pdbYz/) shows the jumping text on mouse hovering
Could I somehow prevent the jumping of text while keeping the appearance of scroll bar on hover?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use `<p>` tag for your text like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/pdbYz/6/

UPDATE for firefox:

http://jsfiddle.net/pdbYz/19/

Comment: Thanks for answering but i still see text jumping in FireFox and IE9. (works in Chrome)

Comment: you are right . so you can set width for <p> elements some pixel less than it's parent .

Answer (score 1):

I propose to have another container within `div#scroll` with fixed, slightly smaller width.
This way your text won't 'jump' when scroll appears. Since scrollbars have different width on different OS (Windows, Mac, Linux) you should leave some free space to the right, where scrollbar appears.

Please see my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/5RXSW/

To make containers more visible I've applied paddings and background colors. You can tweak these styles for your needs, but please reserve some pixels to the right of `div#scroll` for scrollbar.

Answer (score -1):

You can change the width of the container on hover, so that when the scrollbar appears, it pushes outwards instead of inwards. This prevents the text from moving.

http://jsfiddle.net/pdbYz/3/

To achieve this I've added this line to your CSS:

```
#scroll:hover {
    width: 360px;
}
```

Comment: Text still 'jumps'. FireFox, Win7